# KAA Failed to create kaa_configuration_manager_set_root_receiver

Tags: c, kaa

I want to control GPIO of endpoint (Raspberry pi 3).

I try to merge two KAA demo applications to one. ("Cassandra data analytics" and "Data collection")

Since there is only one demo for Raspberry Pi, I choose "Cassandra data analytics".

And I have used "Data collection demo" to control endpoint from kaa server.

Now, I want to implement control GPIO of endpoint from kaa server on "Cassandra data analytics".

Here is my procedure:

1. Choose  Application -> "Cassandra data analytics" on WEB UI.
2. Add new schema (Configuration schemas) follow "Data collection demo"
   and I modify temperature to GPIO_PIN_4 (integer type).
3. Generate SDK.
4. Copy *tar.gz to "libs" folder
5. Modify kaa_demo.c,

   1. add header file

      ```
      #include "extensions/configuration/kaa_configuration_manager.h"
      #include "extensions/configuration/kaa_configuration_manager.c"
      ```
   2. Configure notification manager in `main()`

      ```
      kaa_configuration_root_receiver_t receiver = {
          .context = NULL,
          .on_configuration_updated = on_configuration_updated
      };

      error_code = kaa_configuration_manager_set_root_receiver(
          kaa_client_get_context(kaa_client)->configuration_manager,
          &receiver);
      ```

Here, I got `error_code = -4`

Is anyone can tell me how to solve this error?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error codes are defined in the [src/kaa/kaa_error.h](https://github.com/kaaproject/kaa/blob/master/client/client-multi/client-c/src/kaa/kaa_error.h#L38) file. The particular error `-4` is defined as `KAA_ERR_BADPARAM`, which means one of the parameters is wrong.

If you check [source code for `kaa_configuration_manager_set_root_receiver`](https://github.com/kaaproject/kaa/blob/release-0.10/client/client-multi/client-c/src/extensions/configuration/kaa_configuration_manager.c#L300-L307) function, it becomes obvious that one of the parameters is `NULL`. `&receiver` is guaranteed to be non-null, so the wrong parameter must be `kaa_client_get_context(kaa_client)->configuration_manager`.

This is likely due to configuration extension been disabled. `-DWITH_EXTENSION_CONFIGURATION=ON` must be passed to the C SDK cmake command. Check your CMake file and change `WITH_EXTENSION_CONFIGURATION` value to `ON`.